# What's the diference between [attr.name] and [name]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a question about the `[attr.name]` and `[name]`,I'm using `querySelectorAll` in my ts in the next form =>

```
this._document.querySelectorAll("input[name="+'checkModel-'"]")
```

and if I define in the html like this->

```
<input [name]="checkModel-" type="checkbox">
```

I get the nodeList empty, while I do

```
<input [attr.name]="checkModel-" type="checkbox">
```

The nodelist returns the value/values expected, is there any diference between those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input HTML element has an attribute called "name". It is used to set the name of the given control. For some reason your property binding may not be working due to an unclosed tag or a mistake with the HTML syntax.

**Property Binding**

```
<input [value]="yourVariableName" />
```

Bind the values of the properties in any given control or HTML element to a variable or method. For this to work properly you have to use an existing HTML attribute like "name", "max", "min", "type". If you don't, the following error will occur:

```
Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'data-username' since it isn't a known native property
```

**Attribute Binding**

```
<input [attr.name]="yourVariableName" />
```

Not too different from the other, the attribute binding creates a new flag or property that is attached to the element for future use. It is used mostly when you want to add some extra data to the element with an attribute that didn't had before. Commonly used to solve the previous error from the property binding.